# Change position of subscript locally

Tags: equations, subscripts

When I write `\eta_{PV}` in an equation I get a very unpleasent result:
[image: eta with subscript]

I would like to have the subscript lower than the greek letter.
I know that can be achieved by
 `\fontdimen16\textfont2=5pt \fontdimen17\textfont2=5pt` 
which will give me a really nice result:[image: eta enhanced subscript]

Problem is, this will change the subscript level in my whole equation and the rest of the document.

How can I change the subscript level lower just for eta or just locally?

Comment: `\eta\strut_{PV}` ?

Comment: Are you aware of `\eta_{PV}^{}`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  This does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\eta\strut_{PV}` so that the subscript is the depth of a strut (or more generally you can make a 0-width rule of whatever depth you need to push the subscript down)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against `\eta\strut_{PV}`.

Here is an example. I use `\eta^{}_{PV}` in the first two cases, that end up in consecutive lines and also `\eta\strut_{PV}` in the second two cases.

As you can see, the consecutive lines where the `\strut` construction is used are spread further apart because of the strut *with* the subscript.

The lines containing `\eta^{}_{PV}`, to the contrary, are at the standard baseline skip distance from each other.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
$\eta^{}_{PV}$
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
$\eta^{}_{PV}$
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
$\eta\strut_{PV}$
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
$\eta\strut_{PV}$
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a close up of the three possibilities: first is `\eta_{PV}`, second is `\eta^{}_{PV}`, third is `\eta\strut_{PV}`. You can judge what's best, taking into account the problem explained above. The close up also reveals a bad kerning in the `\strut` case.

[image]

If you load `amsmath` (which is recommended for documents with math), you could do

```
\eta{\smash[t]{\strut}}_{PV}
```

but the problem with spread apart lines might appear anyway, because the subscript is very low.